# Tangent identity

Tags: trigonometry

I came across this in a paper, and although I suspect its extremely elementary, I can't quite grasp it.

Suppose we have vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{x}^{\prime}$. As a given, we have

\begin{equation}
\tan\left[2\Theta(\vec{x}-\vec{x}^{\prime})\right] = \frac{2(x_{1}-x_{1}^{\prime})\cdot(x_{2}-x_{2}^{\prime})}{(x_{1}-x_{1}^{\prime})^{2}-(x_{2}-x^{\prime}_{x})^{2}}
\end{equation}

with $x_{1,2}$ just the components of the vector (say in the $x$ and $y$ direction).

Is there any logic to this expression?

Furthermore, judging by the paper I should be able to infer *from* this expressions for $\cos\left[2\Theta(\vec{x}-\vec{x}^{\prime})\right]$ and $\sin\left[2\Theta(\vec{x}-\vec{x}^{\prime})\right]$ (in terms of $x_{1,2}$ and $x_{1,2}^{\prime}$) but I wouldn't know how to do that.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like an application of the double angle formula: $$ tan (2\theta) =  \frac{2 \tan(\theta)}{1 - \tan^2(\theta)}$$. Here $$\tan(\theta) = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$ and therefore $$\tan(2 \theta) = \frac{ 2 \Delta x \Delta y}{\Delta x^2 - \Delta y^2}$$. You have $$\Delta x = x_1 - x_1'$$ and $$\Delta y = x_2 - x_2'$$. It seems to work out. Thanks

Comment: By the way, the double angle formula for $$\sin(2 \theta) = 2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)$$. You can use the fact that $$\sin(\theta) = \frac{\Delta y}{\sqrt{ \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}}$$ and $$\cos(\theta) = \frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{ \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}}$$. You can combine this to obtain $$\sin(2 \theta) = \frac{ 2 \Delta x \Delta y}{ \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2} $$.

Comment: $$\cos (2\theta) = \frac{\Delta x^2 - \Delta y^2}{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}$$.